# Xamarin Forms consuming WCF (Dynamics Nav Soap) throw SerializationException

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, xamarin.forms, dynamics-nav

I have generated the Proxy classes for nav with the SvcUtil.exe. I can call functions of Codeunits and Read Records from Pages, but if Dynamics Nav throw an Error i don't get a proper Exception. Im also getting while debbuging following Error Message in Visual Studio:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 'Error in line 1 position 293. Expecting element 'ExceptionDetail' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ServiceModel'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'string', namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/'.'
```

Error in VisualStudio:

[image: Error in VisualStudio]

Comment: worse comes to worse, build a server api that is a wrapper for your WCF services.  Then call the server api through REST from your mobile app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. An own Web Api is my last choice. Is there another choice?

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to do it, but why struggle when it could take less time to spin up an api